make a value available otuside of this function to use in php later
im trying to turn the country_code var outside of the function to use later in a php. Here its working to display the value in a div. The issue im having is making the var available outside of the function, so I can turn it into a php var to use in php script later once a submit button is pressed
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var country_code = this.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").split('loc=');
            
            
            document.getElementById("countrycode-container").innerHTML = country_code;
          }
        };
        //OPEN HTTP Request
        xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", true);
        xhttp.send();
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br><br>
    <div id="countrycode-container"></div>
    <br><br><br>
    </body>
    </html>

but I want to remove the div to use in a php script like this by just making a php var from the value of the javascript
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           
              //start of function
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    let country_code = this.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").split('loc=');
                    country_code = country_code[1].split('tls=');
                    country_code = country_code[0];
                    document.getElementById("countrycode-container").innerHTML = country_code;
                    console.log(country_code);//will work here
                
                  }
            
                  
                };
                //end of function
                
                
                //OPEN HTTP Request
                xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", true);
                xhttp.send();
        
 console.log(country_code);//need it to work here so i can take the value and turn it into php var
        
        // somehow convert from javascript var to php var
        //javascript var country_code
        //php var $country
        
        $country=country_code;
      
   
    
    
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
         code to check country code and do somin if match US,CA
        else{
         if empty or not US or CA do this
        }
        }


I want the JavaScript when page loads to get location and save it as a php var without displaying the input at all it can be set and not used right? and its only 2 options i need usa,canada,mexico do this. or not usa,canada,mexico do thaT

Please append new details to he question body via an [edit] instead of posting comments under the question.

You can achieve what you want by adding a hidden input in the form like this:
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="path/to/script.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="country_code" id="country_code" value=""/>
   <!-- ... -->
   <input id="submitButtonElement" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled />
</form>

Then slightly change your JavaScript:
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var variables = Object.fromEntries
    (
      this.responseText
      .split("\r")
      .map
      (
        row => row.trim("\n").split("=")
      )
    );
    var country_code = variables['loc'];
    
    document.getElementById("countrycode-container").innerHTML = country_code;
    
    // EDIT: change the hidden input value
    document.getElementById("country_code").value = country_code;
    
    // Enable the form submission...
    document.getElementById("submitButtonElement").disabled = false;
  }
};
//OPEN HTTP Request
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace", true);
xhttp.send();

Then slightly change your PHP script:
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
  $country = $_POST['country_code'];
  
  // ...
  
  switch ( $country )
  {
    case 'US':
    case 'CA':
    {
      // If US or CA...
      break;
    }
    
    // Add more country options here...
    /*
    case 'BR':
    {
      // If BR...
      break;
    }
    */
    
    default:
    {
      // If none of the above...
      break;
    }
  }
  
  // ...
}

The page will request the country from the tracer then store the value in the form to send via POST method to be available in PHP. You should disable the submit button until the country variable is set.
This should pretty much work. But note that only the receiving PHP script will have access to the $_POST['country_code']. The PHP script that generates the form will not have access to that $country variable. But if the form is sent once you can store the value in a session variable and restore it in other PHP scripts. In this latter case, you should initialize a default value for the country variable in the session if there's none.

It is probably worth noting that if the country code value has to be fetched via XHR, presumably from the same server to which the fetched code will be sent back, the second PHP code could just as well fetch the country code on the back end from the same service. That way the client only has to make one HTTP request for it. Or, the country code could be looked up at the server and rendered with the page originally.

I want the JavaScript when page loads to get location and save it as a php var without displaying the input at all it can be set and not used right? and its only 2 options i need usa,canada,mexico do this not usa,canada,mexico do thaT

@Pointy I think that if the request to the tracer is made from the server side like it's done in the example code then it'll return the country of the server not the client. I also think this approach is not very good because it can be hacked and that there must be some api provided by the tracer that would allow retrieving the request route and infer the country from where it comes from...

Is it not possible to set value on page load and turn it to php without placing it in in input?

console.log(country_code);//will work here so it grabs the user  location based on ip and their cloudflare server that i make the http request too if u use a proxy from uk or whatever ull see it work

The m pattern modifier has no effect on the written pattern.  There is no ^ or $ in the pattern.  m does not mean that the input string has multiple lines.

@qwerty321 You can retrieve the country code with ajax in JavaScript just like its already done and then make another ajax request (with POST method) to some script in PHP that will update the country variable in the PHP session. You could store the country code in the hidden input value and use afterwards (or not). You can also store the country code in a localStorage variable and retrieve from there between pages on client side without the need to request the code from the tracer again and again... Just do it whenever it's not defined in the localStorage.

@mickmackusa Thanks, I didn't evaluate the pattern and just pasted it from the OP code... You're totally right.

I recommend never transcribing any content from the question to the answer unless it fully represents the best of your current knowledge.  Otherwise unknowing readers will assume it is best practice.
